# Android: Set minimum length for password in EditText without storing it

Tags: security, passwords

I'm working with an application which requires users to login. So for the users to enter their Username and Password, I've created two EditText widgets. Now for the widget taking the password, I want to ensure that the user types in a minimum of say, 8 characters. To do this, Im storing the text entered in a temporary String variable and then checking the variable. Will doing so create a security leak? Will someone be able to hack in to the app and read the password on the device?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on what you're checking the string against. How are passwords stored? The fact that you're assigning the value of the password EditText widget to a string doesn't increase your vulnerability; someone in a position to read that string variable will also be able to read the EditText widget.

Comment: Thanks. That kind of answers my question. But that does raise another. Who can get into a position of reading the widget? Or rather how does one do it?

Comment: I'm not super-knowledgeable on that, I believe the technical term for a computer where a malicious actor can read data directly from running applications is "royally pwned". At that point the malicious actors probably have keyloggers running as well, so additional protections in your application against reading username and password data real-time are moot. By far the biggest risk with password data is with improper storage. It needs to be PBKDF2, bcrypt, or equivalent.